# Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls TreeView Not working IE 11

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, treeview, internet-explorer-11

I am using Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls TreeView which does not work in IE11. Has anyone experienced the same?

I am getting the following error on the client side in IE 11 only

Object doesn't support property or method 'getTreeNode'

and

Even the selectedNodeIndex is 'undefined'

We have a legacy product and changing the control would make a huge impact.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem in one of hour old applications. The problems is due to the facts the IE 11 does not identify itself as Internet Explorer (in the same way as before) anymore. What I had to do was to make a patch in the TreeView source code.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is the patch that you have applied to make to work for IE 11

Comment: I cant seem to find that code. But it was the part that identified which browser it is. Had to include the new IE 11 user agent.

Comment: Any idea on what to do after identifying the browser? Did you make changes to the original TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue today!

First, if your IIS runs on older Windows, make sure that
[KB2836940](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2836940) or [KB2836942](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2836942) is installed.

Then, modify the source code of IE WebControls. At [BaseRichControl.cs] line 76:

```
protected virtual BrowserLevelChecker CreateLevelChecker()
{
    //return new BrowserLevelChecker("ie", 5, 0.5, true);
    BrowserLevelChecker _BrowserLevelChecker = new BrowserLevelChecker("ie", 5, 0.5, true);
    _BrowserLevelChecker.Add("InternetExplorer", 11, 0, true);    //add IE11 support
    _BrowserLevelChecker.Add("Mozilla", 11, 0, true);    //sometimes ASP.NET see IE11 as Mozilla Browser
    return _BrowserLevelChecker;
}
```

Rebuild the source code and put the new "Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.dll" in your website's "bin" folder.

Now Treeview should work on IE11.

Hope this would help.

Comment: thank you for your reply Andy. But is it legal to edit the microsoft source code.

Comment: Microsoft did provide full source code of  IE WebControls, but didn't mention license info in README file. So I am not sure about that.

Comment: Hi Andy thank you so much for the help. But i am not able to find the source code for IE web Controls. Can you please let me know where can i find the source code and how to rebuild it using new IDE

Comment: @user2236250 You can get the source code from [here](https://github.com/mmaxim/FrontDesk/tree/master/IEWebControls) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12944868/5189030)

Comment: hi Andy thanks a lot. We had been struggling with this for so many days. Thanks for your help on this